# What is the best way to write a dictionary of column connection with column2?

Tags: python

How to create dictionary of connecting *column* index selection:

data:

```
  No_1         C_N                 
   1            1    
   1            2         
   1            7   
   2           13      
   2            6
```

desired output should be like {1:[1,2,7],2:[13,6]}
I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('connection.csv' ,sep=',')
for i ,j in zip(range(166),df['No_1']):
    if i==j:
      print(df['C_N'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.groupby('No_1')['C_N'].apply(list).to_dict()`.

This gives you `{1: [1, 2, 7], 2: [13, 6]}`.